How to setup Hashicorp Vault Enterprise Secrets Sync with GitHub Enterprise
I am trying to configure the Hashicorp Vault Enterprise Secrets Sync functionality with a GitHub Enterprise instance. However, I do not see a field to configure the base URL of GitHub. It seems to default to github.com, or that's the only possibility right now. The destination endpoint /sys/sync/destinations/gh/:name does not seem to have an option for overriding the GitHub URL. I thought I could use a GitHub App, but that endpoint sys/sync/github-apps/:name in Vault also doesn't appear to let us set the GitHub URL.
Do these two endpoint look correct, or am I overlooking another API endpoint or method of enabling secrets sync to a GitHub Enterprise instance?

As of this writing, this has been confirmed by official support that Vault Enterprise is not available for use with GitHub Enterprise. A feature request has been submitted.

don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer - it's totally legit to answer your own questions here.

Hm - I think you're right. I also don't see any way to configure the actual github URL, like if you're using your own GH Enterprise server. Since this is a paid feature in the Vault Enterprise SKU, you'll do best to contact support and your solutions engineer. And if you get an answer, provide it here!

I opened a support ticket yesterday and will report back.
